# C++ api to develop over Active Directory

Tags: c++, active-directory

I need to access the Active Directory data programmatically using a native C++ API because I like C++ and I think it is faster than any .NET programming language.
I could not find a C++ API developed by Microsoft, it only has a C one (ADSI) and it is really an awful API. I found a C++ API in open LDAP but it has some errors and it seems that the development was abandoned.
Can anyone share about a place to find a decent C++ API to access Active Directory methods?
Regards.

Comment: It's faster for some things, but I'm certain you could get a working C# version of this in no time flat, and with little effort at that.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is going to be pretty difficult to find another friendly API for accessing Active Directory(I could be wrong), but I have heard of a book that covers LDAP/ADSI in c++ very well. It's an older book but it seems to have very good content. It might be your best bet. Like Steven said, it may just be easier to use c# but if that's not an option, try the book out. Good luck and I hope this helps!

[http://www.amazon.com/Active-Directory-Programming-Gil-Kirkpatrick/dp/0672315874/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1247459890&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672315874)